# Issue with session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue.I am working on a project in codeigniter  I am sending some value in session variable and working fine in all the devices and network except Vodafone internet connection.

for EX.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id','5');

echo $this->session->userdata('id');
```

This is not working on mobile only with Vodafone internet on mobile rest is working fine on all the network. Any solution?

Comment: vodafone network means??

Comment: I mean vodafone internet network on mobile devices

Comment: are you sure about the problem??

Comment: Yes I have tested on other connection with airtel internet idea and all other connection on mobile working fine for me except vodafone internet.

Comment: If it is working for other mobile networks, I doubt it is an issue with CI. You may try contacting vodafone and asking them if there is an issue with Cookies that they receive from your website?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have load library as well

In `__construct`

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

or

In `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Comment: It is working for other mobile networks, so he likely has the right libraries included.

Comment: I have loaded my library $autoload['libraries'] = array('session'); in config file already

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter file session not work for mobile, instead of file you should save session in database. First create table in database and change some lines in your config file.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,`ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,`timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,`data` blob NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`));

$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: Huh? Where did you get this erroneous information. It works on mobile.

Comment: check on oreo devices on chrome browser, and do R&D

Comment: I had got session problem on oreo devices on chrome browser so I did that and fix the problem